# Storing an unsigned integer in std::any

Tags: c++, stl

Can I make `::std::any` hold an unsigned integer? Something like:

```
::std::any a = 4;
unsigned int x = ::std::any_cast<unsigned int>(a);
```

results in an `::std::bad_any_cast` exception because `a` actually holds a signed integer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, just put an unsigned integer in it:

```
::std::any a = 4u;
// or
::std::any a = static_cast<unsigned>(4);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vzrYnKKe9

---

I have to caution you. `std::any` is not a magical tool to convert C++ into a dynamically typed language like python or javascript. Its use cases are very narrow and specific. It's not really meant to be used in user code as a "catch all" type. It's meant as a type safe alternative to `void *` in low level library code.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `4` is an `int` by default.

You need to specify unsigned when you fill the `std::any` variable:

```
std::any a = 4u;
unsigned int x = std::any_cast<unsigned int>(a);
```